# ASP MVC - Upload Rar Files with FTP

Tags: model-view-controller

I have this code to upload a rar file to server and this works. But when i download the file from server, contents of file are spoiled. Please tell me how can I fix that. Thanks.

```
public ActionResult UpFile(HttpPostedFileBase upFile)
    {
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upFile.FileName);
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://myhostaddress.com/" + fileName);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUserName", "MyPassword");


        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(upFile.InputStream);
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        streamReader.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;


        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        return RedirectToAction("/");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working for me, try it:

```
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp + fileName);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);

        using (var input = File.OpenRead(filePth))
        {
            using (var output = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                input.CopyTo(output);
            }
        }

        var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        response.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.